# TFS - Global list contains generic project name

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I have defined a WIT with the following field :

```
<FIELD name="Environment" refname="Integration.Environment" type="String">
    <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
      <GLOBALLIST name="Environment - [project]" />
    </ALLOWEDVALUES>
  </FIELD>
```

TFS doesn't translate [project] with the project name.
Do you know, what is the good syntax ?

For example, it works for :

```
<FIELD name="Assigned To" refname="System.AssignedTo" type="String">
    <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="false" not="[global]\Management">
      <LISTITEM value="[project]\Intégration" />
    </ALLOWEDVALUES>
  </FIELD>
```

Answer (score 1):

TFS only translates the project tags for things other than accounts at project creation time.

You need to use the explicit name going forward.

Comment: Thanks, in my case I would like to use [project] at creation time of the WIT. I would like that each TeamProject have custom global list of environment with the same WIT.

Comment: Look at how the build global list is configured in the default template.